# GIT error: key does not contain a section: user-mail

Tags: git

Fiz a seguinte sequencia depois da instalação do GIT no meu note com windows 10:

$ `git config --global user.name "Fabrício Valle"` 
$ `git config --global user.mail "meu email"`

*informei meu email corretamente, com domínio próprio. Usei também com outro email, do gmail.

**Nesse passo, deu o seguinte erro:**

> ~$ git config --global user-mail
>   "recursos@fabriciovalle.com.br" error: key does not contain a section:
>   user-mail

---

Comment: O mesmo com o comando $ git config --global core-editor subl
deu o mesmo erro de "key does..."
error: key does not contain a section: core-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando correto é `git config --global user.email "recursos@fabriciovalle.com.br"`.
**você se esqueceu do 'e' em email e separou as palavras com um traço em vez um ponto**

Esses três links devem ser úteis para você: 
- [Git - Lista de comandos úteis](https://gist.github.com/leocomelli/2545add34e4fec21ec16)
- [Git - Guia prático](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html)
- [Git - Documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2)

Comment: Resolvido. Mas, toda vez que for usar o git terei que executar o .exe dele? Cada vez que o fecho e depois recorro a ele novamente, é solicitada uma nova instalação. É a primeira vez na vida que instalo um .exe no windows e acontece isso.

Comment: Que bom que foi resolvido. Neste caso, marque esta resposta como correta por favor. E bem, procure sempre desconfiar de situações como essa Fabrício, se parece estranho é porque muito provavelmente há algo errado. Não é normal ter que reinstalar qualquer programa a cada uso. Estude um pouco por uma solução e se necessário, publique uma nova pergunta relatando o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Se for só clicar no "V" , já está marcada como melhor resposta. Obrigado.